# Laravel data to javascript could this be insecure and an open vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have this method in the controller:

```
$ep = new Enterprise;
$d = new Chat;
$dataDao = new Data2;
$model = new Data;
$empresa = $ep->getEnterprise();
$tmp_talent = new Talent();
$nm = $d->all($request->session()->get('user')->email);
$data = [
    0 => $empresa,
    'vacantes' => $tmp_talent->getOpenJobsXTalent($request->session()->get('user')->email),
    "messages" => $nm,
    "userId"=> $dataDao->getMyUserId(),
    "categories"=>$model->getCategories(),
    //"subcategories"=>$model->getSubCategories()
];
return view('chat.dash')->with('data',$data);
```

And this is their corresponding resource file:

```
<script>
    var allMessages = {!! json_encode($data['messages']) !!};
```

My question is if this can represent a vulnerability than an attacker could use to make damage on my site or to my end users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re displaying unescaped data
Which shouldn’t be used for displaying users entries

You are using json here so you want to use `@json()`

Or

```
<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

[Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade)

Comment: Thanks, but still I have the doubt how can someone use the fact of the unescaped data to inject their own data and/or code. If the issue is only the unescaped data that means that something like `<?php echo json_encode(DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($array);  ?>;` would do the trick?

Comment: Or something like `<?php echo json_encode(addslashes(DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($array)); ?>;`

Comment: you don't need to do that you just make sure `"messages" => $nm,` is secured with validation

Answer (score 0):

Those data could be a vulnerability if they are confidential and you also have an XSS vulnerability which allows an attacker to get them.